# rdlc Reports in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dataset, reporting, rdlc

I am working on RDLC report in c #
I have a data base schema as follow

```
Contact Class:

String name;
int mobile_id

Mobile Class:

string number
```

where a contact can have multiple mobile numbers.

I want to show the records on report such that against every contact'name all its mobile numbers are shown. How to get this?

Comment: any one here for help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a class that has the schema that you want to show. ie

```
class ContactReport
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public sting Number {get;set;}
}
```

Use that class as a report datasource in the report designer, create an instance  and populate it in code and the assign it to the local report of the report viewer.
since WOPF doesn't support the report viewer, you have to create a windows form viewer and host it in WPF.

Comment: but how one name can have mutliple numbers? how could i show them again single name?

Comment: yes i have added windows form viewer and hosted report viewer

Comment: List<ContactReport> list = new List<ContactReport> ();

Comment: list.Add(new ContactReport("Luciano","123456")); list.Add(new ContactReport("Luciano","78901231"))

Comment: but then name will repeat

Comment: If you don't want to show the Name multiple times, you should use grouping and put the Name in the header of the group.

Comment: It will not repeat if you use grouping. That's the whole point of grouping. You group by Name, then put the  Name on the header and you can put the count(Number) in the footer of the group.

Comment: thank you. i am retrieving data from database using join.also i need to filter result using parameters.for example if user enters "john and Anna" then only records having name john or anna will be shown?how could i get this?

Comment: in rdlc report should i use grouping on rows?

Comment: you have removed a big hurdle from my way :)

Comment: Yes. Group on rows. Regarding the filter, it will be better let sql do the filtering using a where clause.

Comment: i am using entity framework. and it means when i need to add a proper where clause in my query while retrieving data?

Comment: Use the linq "where" keyword to execute EF filtered queries.

Comment: var q=from u in db.Contact where u.Name=="John" || u.Name==Anna Select u. that  what u mean?

Comment: I have tried this solution but unable to do successfull grouping on data